# How does the handling of combining characters in the Unicode Collation Algorithm work?

Tags: unicode, uca

I maintain an open-source, pure-Python implementation of the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/) called [**pyuca**](https://github.com/jtauber/pyuca).

While it meets my needs in sorting Ancient Greek text (and seems to meet the needs of many other people), I'm looking to improve its coverage of rarer cases by getting it to the point where it passes the entire suite of [official conformance tests](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/6.3.0/CollationTest.html).

However, 1,869 of the tests (just over 1%) fail. The first failure is at `0332 0334` which the test files suggest should get the sort key `| 004A 0021 | 0002 0002 |`.

**pyuca**, however, forms the sort key `| 0021 004A | 0002 0002 |`.

At first I thought this might be due to lack of support for non-starter characters ([S2.1.1 thru S2.1.3 of the algorithm in the latest spec](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/tr10-28.html#Step_2)). However, my subsequent implementation of this part did nothing to change the sort key and a manual working through the algorithm on paper also fails to trigger that section which has me wondering if I'm just missing something.

The relevant steps in the algorithm are:

**S2.1.1** If there are any non-starters following S, process each non-starter C.
**S2.1.2** If C is not blocked from S, find if S + C has a match in the table.
**S2.1.3** If there is a match, replace S by S + C, and remove C.

The key phrase is "If there is a match". In the test mentioned above that fails, there *is* no match for `0332 0334` and so this part of the algorithm *cannot* explain why the sort key should be in a different order to what my implementation produces.

Can anyone explain what part of the UCA would form a sort key like the test file suggests?

Comment: for anyone coming across this later, pyuca now passes 100% of the conformance test suite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does it work better if you shove the string into Normalization Form D first? (Step 1.)

This is an utter wild guess based on the fact that `0332 0334` is not in NFD. I haven't tried to work through the algorithm at all.

Comment: I'll definitely try that. In normal usage, I always pass in NFD but (perhaps foolishly) didn't think to do that as part of running the compliance tests.

Comment: Well, that did it. Down to 85 failures instead of 1,869. As is often the case, the answer turned out to be much simpler than I thought and I was going down the wrong rabbit hole. Thanks very much!

Comment: FYI here is some reference code (in Java) together with an online applet demo that you might find helpful with chasing down the rest of those test cases, if you aren't already aware of it: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/Sample/